# Calculate kappa score for multi label image classifcation

Tags: python, confusion-matrix

I want to calculate kappa score for a multi label image classification problem.

I don't think sklearn supports this inherently because when i try this

```
import sklearn
sklearn.metrics.cohen_kappa_score(y_test, predictions)
```

i get

```
ValueError: multilabel-indicator is not supported
```

anyone has suggestions on how to do this?
My prediction matrix is of shape(845,8) with 0 and 1 in them.
My ground truth matrix is of shape (845,8) with 0 and 1 in them

My labels look like this

```
[0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0]
```

thanks in advance.

#######EDIT

please provide relevant code.Alteast a small snippet.

Answer (score 7):

**Cohen's kappa by definition does not support multiple labels**

This is because Cohen's kappa is given by K = (po - pe)/(1 - pe)

where po = (TP + FN)/(TP + TN + FP + FN)

and   pe = (TN + FP)/(TP + TN + FP + FN)

As you can see it is calculated using Confusion matrix.You can construct a confusion matrix only for mutually exclusive labels(ex: [0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0]) and not for non exclusive labels(ex: [0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0])

If using Cohen's kappa is a priority i would recommend calculating it separately for each and every label and then averaging them.

Or else the best course of action here would be to use **Krippendorff's Alpha**

Krippendorff’s alpha (also called Krippendorff’s Coefficient) is an alternative to Cohen’s Kappa for determining inter-rater reliability.

reference links: [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Krippendorff%27s_alpha) , [statisticshowto](https://www.statisticshowto.datasciencecentral.com/krippendorffs-alpha/)

Although Krippendorff's Alpha isn't available in sklearn library you can use it using this package [krippendorff](https://pypi.org/project/krippendorff/)

```py
import krippendorff
reliability_data = [[prediction matrix],[ground truth]]
print(krippendorff.alpha(reliability_data=reliability_data))
```

```py
print([prediction matrix].shape,[ground truth].shape)
```

(845,8) , (845,8)

hope this helps

Comment: Can you describe that in your answer please?

Comment: the `krippendorff.alpha(reliability_data)` takes in a single matrix , but i have two matrices, predictions and true labels.

Comment: refer to sample.py here [link](https://github.com/pln-fing-udelar/fast-krippendorff/blob/master/sample.py) . here reliability_data = [[prediction matrix],[ground truth matrix]]. I hope this helps

Answer (score 4):

## Krippendorff's Alpha

You can NOT use Cohen's Kappa for a multilabel agreement. The solution is to use **Krippendorff's Alpha**.

However, Krippendorff's Alpha can be used with many different data types and you need to remember that you have **nominal data** (i.e. classes).

## Code

You can use the `krippendorff` package found here: https://github.com/pln-fing-udelar/fast-krippendorff

Notice that the `alpha()` function has a parameter `level_of_measurement`, which by default is `interval`, so you need to set it to `nominal`!

```
import krippendorff

reliability_data = [[predictions], [y_test]]

print(krippendorff.alpha(reliability_data=reliability_data, 
                         level_of_measurement='nominal'))
```

Comment: Thanks Bruno.  I am trying to understand the code you shared here. is [predictions] mean the columns we have labeled? do you have any chance to show how the data would like before this calculation? I am trying to make sure I have done the right preprocessing :) thanks btw, you provided an amazing insight.